# Randomly UITableViewCell getting dark black selection color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, selection

In my application I have several TaBleViews, on selection in these tableviews app navigates back and forth. Sometimes selecting a cell on any of the tableview turns the selection color from default gray to dark black, it happens on random basis means the cell which shows black once, shows gray other time. I don't know why it is happening, please do suggest what can be the reason for this. Is this an iOS bug?

The screenshots are as:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: check my answer i have edited

Comment: check my answer i have edited –

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug, it is like a marker that the cell is selected.

If you dont want to `.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` and preserver the `highlight` gray color;

You have to deselect the cell then, like:

**Obj-C**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

**Swift**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
{
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: It's okay about graycolor, I am also deselecting the cell on the selection and all cells are set to have gray selection style, but why randomly some cell gets the dark black background (see pictures) on selection that's the point of discussion.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

Select your table in storyboard Click on `show the attribute inspector` and deselect `Show Selection on Touch` option.

in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method write

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` write

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, no dark selection but, now I am getting the other problem, when I return to table view then cell stays with dark background.

Comment: Ok, for some table deseletion was missing, anyways thanx.

Comment: Opps, I am still getting this on selection. See the last picture.

Comment: Sorry, If I will set selection style to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone then I will not get the desired gray selection.